# Is there conditional caching in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Is there a built-in asp.net way to conditionally serve pages, for example I want the following logic:

> If there is a session data I generate
>   a page, if there is no session data I
>   serve the cached page.

I am only interested in knowing about a built-in asp.net mechanism for this. If it does not exist I am probably going to simply cache my page manually and decide whether to serve it or not for each request, based on the session data availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is built-in support (like `varyByParam`) for generating fresh output for users with Session Data.

As you suggest, I would recommend manually caching the pages. I would probably determine the user's Session state in the `PreRequestHandlerExecute` event handler in the `Global.asax` and then maybe set:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of karmabombing, I really don't like this approach to caching.

For me if a GET request is made, then a server should respond to that in good faith. Caching at a page level should be controlled by http headers because the primary goal is not to get the redundant request *at all* - you don't want to allocate server/bandwidth resources full stop.

Caching objects which are resources involved in making up a page I can totally get behind, but I can't see great arguments for caching a page wholesale.

Respect the headers.

Comment: Technically entity tags (HTTP 1.1) could be used here without going against what you mentioned (which I agree with).

Comment: sure, as could HEAD requests, but it's about support - I'm saying the concept is flawed from the get go

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the substitution control ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160911080823/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/05/04/39003.aspx)) new in .NET 2.0, however it might not be exactly what you are after.